# Caja to perform instant search like Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, filemanager, caja

Between these 2 file managers, I like Caja more. But the only thing I like about Nautilus is the search feature.

[Nautilus does instant search once we type anything](https://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2019/05/comparing-search-between-nautilus-and-nemo.html).

[image]

It does not need Find button to search, as it instantly search as we type.

It's almost similar to incremental search we know in Google Web Search as suggestions appear instantly once we type.

Is it possible to make Caja to perform instant search just like Nautilus?

Is there any other file manager that has similar feature like this?

Comment: Well, it's not that nemo/caja/thunar(?) don't perform a search when you type, they just don't *filter* the files with the pattern...